# Avoid repetation of error message in addError()

Tags: error

How to avoid repetition of same message at addError()/addSuccess().

Example:

```
public function a(){
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("Custom Error");
}


public function b(){
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("Custom Error");
}
```

In some cases I call both function a() and function b().
I don't want both error message at a time.

Comment: You should give more details about your issue. This is very unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `addUniqueMessages` method from the session.
But the problem is that you have to pass as parameter an instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Message_Abstract` or an array with instances of the same class.
So your code should look like this:

```
public function a(){
    $message = Mage::getModel('core/message_error', 'Custom Error');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addUniqueMessages($message);
}


public function b(){
    $message = Mage::getModel('core/message_error', 'Custom Error');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addUniqueMessages($message);
}
```

The example above is for error messages. but it works for other types:

`core/message_success`, `core/message_notice`, `core/message_warning`

Answer (score 0):

**Admin**

```
$message = Mage::getModel('core/message_error', $message);
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->addUniqueMessages($message);
```

**Front End**

```
$message = Mage::getModel('core/message_error', 'Custom Error');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addUniqueMessages($message);
```